# shocking to me vs shocking for me

Tags: meaning, differences

> The news is shocking *to me*.

vs

> The news is shocking *for me*.

and

> *For me*, the cooking style is useless

vs

> *To me*, the cooking style is useless.

I think these two sentences are exactly the same. Is there anyone who can help me to tell the difference?